# React JS Material UI Select IconComponent (Dropdown Icon) avoid rotating

Tags: reactjs, select, material-ui

By default, in React JS Material UI's Select component, when we provide a custom IconComponent, it gets turned upside down when user has selected the dropdown / Select component.

[image]

Sample code:

```
<Select
  multiple
  variant="outlined"
  MenuProps={CustomMenuProps}
  IconComponent={Search}
  renderValue={(selected) => (selected as string[]).join(', ')}
  {...props}
>
...
```

I did a sneaky thing to remove `"MuiSelect-iconOpen"` from the `className` when calling IconComponent.

[image]

Sample Code after my fix:

```
<Select
  multiple
  variant="outlined"
  MenuProps={CustomMenuProps}
  IconComponent={({ className }) => {
    className = className.replace("MuiSelect-iconOpen", "")
    return <Search className={className} />
  }}
  renderValue={(selected) => (selected as string[]).join(', ')}
  {...props}
>
....
```

Now is there a better way to do this without replacing the className?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My current solution is to overwrite the original `iconOpen` class provided by the Material-UI Select.

```
....
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  iconOpen: {
    transform: 'rotate(0deg)',
  },
}));

....
export const MyCompo: FC<> = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Select
      multiple
      variant="outlined"
      MenuProps={CustomMenuProps}
      IconComponent={Search}
      classes={{
        iconOpen: classes.iconOpen,
      }}
      renderValue={(selected) => (selected as string[]).join(', ')}
      {...props}
    >
....
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<Select
    value={values.phoneCode}
    onChange={handleChange("phoneCode")}
    inputProps={{ "aria-label": "Without label" }}
    IconComponent={(_props) => {
        const rotate = _props.className.toString().includes("iconOpen");
        return (
            <div
                style={{
                     position: "absolute",
                     cursor: "pointer",
                     pointerEvents: "none",
                     right: 10,
                     height: "15px",
                     width: "15px",
                     transform: rotate ? "rotate(180deg)" : "none",
                }}
             >
                <ArrowDown />
            </div>
         );
       }}
     >
....
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

It does not rotate if you use arrow function: `IconComponent={()=> <YourIcon/>}`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).